# How to Initialize UIImageViews etc. and show them on screen : iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview, declaration

Okay, I'm new to programming in XCode and Objective-C, and have a question.

I can add a UIImageView normally using the drag and drop features in the Storyboard Builder thing. Then I can access it in code by creating a connection to the relavent ViewController, with a control drag and drop and then I can create a outlet. It is then declared in the *.h file with the @property line and synthesized in the *.m file.

BUT, what if I have a more complex view and it would take far too long drop and drag everything onto the screen and what if I wanted to change the position of the objects during execution?

I have tried using this in the ViewDidLoad Method:

```
NSMutableArray *mutableArray = [NSMutableArray array];
UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue.png"];
for (int x = 0;x<10;x++){
    for (int y =0;y<10;y++){
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pic];
    imageView.frame =CGRectMake(x*23,y*41,32,41);
[mutableArray addObject:imageView];
    }
}
```

This, I hoped would make a grid of UIImageViews and hold them in a NSMutableArray, but nothing appears on screen. How do you do a similar process to the drag and drop but in code? I realize I'm not synthesizing anything, and I only declare one instance UIImageView, but I thought If I put the declaration in the for loops then it would complain because it would be creating multiple variables with the same name. Is there anyway to create a load of UIImageViews in a few lines of code using a loop? I though of maybe just editing the sting used as the identifier for the pointer variable e.g. "image1", "image2"..... But I didn't know how to use a string type variable as the name of an identifier.

P.S. - I googled the CGRectMake procedure and the parameters are (x-coordinates,y-coordinates,width,height).

Any help would be greatly appreciated :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add them to the subview.

```
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```

Instead of adding them to an array you could use tags to identify the individual `UIImageView`, it all depends on what you prefer.

```
UIImage * pic = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue.png"];
int tagInt=1;
for (int x = 0;x<10;x++){
    for (int y =0;y<10;y++){
        UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pic];
        imageView.frame =CGRectMake(x*23,y*41,32,41);
        imageView.tag=tagInt;
        [self.view addSubview:imageView];
        tagInt++;
    }
}
```

Then to access the individual `UIImageView`

```
UIImageView *imageView = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:1];
```

Comment: So when something is added to the subview that's the same as doing the property/synthesise thing? Also I had no idea the UIImageView and a .tag attribute. How would I go about finding out what all of the attributes an object can hold are?

Comment: It is not the properties that add the subview to the view. When you use `IBOutlet` this creates an outlet of your ui element in interface builder which you can then connect up. But this can just as easily be an ivar and not a property. The above is the coded way (if you like) of doing it.

Comment: I suggest you research about properties, they can be confusing to begin with but are very important. As for finding out all the attributes of an object I would suggest reading the apple docs of when you use a new object and you will find new things out as you go along.

Comment: Okay, so what if I want to change the attributes of the imageViewers after declaration? the only thing that I have to identify them is the tag attribute, since they all have the same identifier (using your method). How would I do this for the imageView with tag 10 for instance? Something like?:
[self.view imageview.tag=10] = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:pic]

Comment: Okay, I have found another problem. One, it doesn't seem to work if you use a tag of value 0, but that doesn't matter. The real problem is that I want to make some sort of grid like game and it only updates the screen once the the method that changes the colour of the imageViewer has finished. But I have a method with an infinite loop in it and it changes the colour of the tiles as you press buttons. The buttons call methods which change a boolean variable to true, so the main game loop knows whats been pressed by constantly checking if certain variables are true.

Comment: But because the game loop never ends the screen is never updated. Is there a way to update what's on the screen during execution?

Comment: Since this is a different question I posted it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12079673/uiimageviewer-doest-update-its-contents-until-methods-finish-not-as-the-comman
if you could answer it I would appreciate it :).

Answer (score 0):

You are holding all the imageView objects you create in a NSMutableArray. You need to add them as a subview of your view (in this case, I am supposing your view is the view of your UIViewController):

```
[self.view addSubview:imageView];
```