# UIImageViewer does't update its contents until methods finish, not as the commands are executed

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiimageview

Okay, I have a problem with my code. I want to make some sort of grid like game using imageViewers, but when the method that changes the pictures which the imageViewers how, it only updates the screen/imageviewers once it is finished executing, not when the line that does it is actually executed. I has a method with an infinite loop in it and it changes the pictures of the imageViewers as you press buttons. The buttons call methods which change a boolean variable to true, so the main game loop knows whats been pressed by constantly checking if certain variables are true. But because the game loop never ends the screen is never updated. Is there a way to update what's on the screen during execution?

I am using this code to change the imageViewers contents:

```
     UIImage * white = [UIImage imageNamed: @"White.png"];
     UIImage * blue = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue.png"];
     int tagInt=1;
     for (int y = 0;y<10;y++){
         for (int x = 0;x<10;x++){
             UIImageView *imageView;
             imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:white];                 imageView.frame =CGRectMake(x*32,y*37,32,37);
             imageView.image = white;
             imageView.tag=tagInt;
             [self.view addSubview:imageView];
             tagInt++;
         }
     }
     for (int u = 1;u<20;u++){
         [NSThread sleepForTimeInterval:(1)];   
         UIImageView *g = (UIImageView*)[self.view viewWithTag:u];
         g.image =blue;
     }
```

This is a contrived example, because my actual code is too long, but has the same problem. It only updates on-screen after the last for loop (this delays/thread-sleep commands) finishes, not as the lines of code execute.

EDIT: Here is the project if you want any context: https://www.dropbox.com/s/cvefllnhgj0tp6g/Stacker.zip

Comment: Why can't you check what variables are true in your button methods and change your image views accordingly in the button method

Comment: Good idea, I suppose that would make more sense. Although the image views are still changing even when no buttons are being pressed. So this alone won't solve my problem. it would however if my games was different in nature :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In iOS, all UI related stuff is done in the main (UI) thread. If you have an operation that blocks the ui thread - which means, it keeps the thread busy as you do - no view update will occur.
So you will have to change your code that way, that you have a "updateView" method which changes the image views' content. This method will have to be called on a regular base, e.g. by using an NSTimer instance: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nstimer_Class/Reference/NSTimer.html

Assuming, the code to update your view is named "updateView", you could define a timer like this:

```
NSTimer *timer;
    timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1
                        target: self 
                        selector:@selector(updateView:) 
                        userInfo: nil 
                        repeats: YES];
```

So the timer would call your updateView method every second and would not block the main thread which again would allow the changes you made to the view to become visible.

Comment: Okay thanks. That makes logical sense. My only questions are:
1) Once the NSTimer is declared does it execute the method specified in the selector all on it's own every interval?
2) Where would you declare this NSTimer? Would I have to do it in the main UI method? I'm not even sure where that is, or would I just declare it as a global variable in the respective ViewController?

Comment: You could declare it for example it the viewDidLoad method. It will start triggering the defined method right after it has been defined - so no further call needed to start it. Strictly speaking, you don't need to hold a reference to it in a member variable, but it would be good practice to do so and to call `[timer invalidate]`when you want to stop it or you don't need it anymore.

Comment: Thanks. The line of code you gave "[timer invalidate]" only seems to work in the method that it was declared. But obviously It's only going to be executing the viewDidLoad method at the start. How can I end the timer in a different way/make that way work?

Comment: `[timer invalidate]`will work anywhere in your class (a view controller I guess) when you define NSTimer *timer not in viewDidLoad but make it a member variable. So you would have the line "NSTimer *timer" in your .h-file (that's one way - there are many others) and only leave the rest of the code in viewDidLoad. By this, the instance of NSTimer you store in the variable timer will be accessible from anywhere in the class. `[timer invalidate]` should then stop the execution immediately.

Comment: Thanks. How would I change the scheduledTimeWithTimeInterval value of the NSTimer? I tried invalidating it then reinitialising it, but it just stopped working.

Comment: That's the right way to go - invalidate and recreate. Hard to say, why it's not working, perhaps you can post some code?

Comment: Okay the invalidate and recreate is working for me now. I have no idea why, but in my (limited) experience with xcode/objective-c, when things don't work, if you simply try them later they do work for no obvious reason!

Answer (score 0):

I think a CA animation will do what you need.  Try something like this:

```
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>

- (void)imageView:(UIImageView *)imageView crossfadeTo:(UIImage *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    [imageView.layer removeAnimationForKey:@"animateContents"];

    CABasicAnimation *crossFade = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"contents"];
    crossFade.duration = duration;
    crossFade.fromValue = (id)imageView.image.CGImage;
    crossFade.toValue = (id)image.CGImage;
    [imageView.layer addAnimation:crossFade forKey:@"animateContents"];

    imageView.image = image;
}
```

This can also be made into a category method on UIImageView.  Call it like this:

```
UIImage *white = [UIImage imageNamed: @"White.png"];
UIImage *blue = [UIImage imageNamed: @"Blue.png"];

UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:white];
[self imageView:imageView crossfadeTo:blue duration:5.0];
```

Alternatively, this can be done with block animation calling it the same way, as follows:

```
- (void)imageView:(UIImageView *)imageView crossfadeTo:(UIImage *)image duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {

    UIImageView *fadeToImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:imageViewFrame];
    fadeToImageView.image = image;
    [imageView.superview insertSubview:fadeToImageView belowSubview:imageView];

    [UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
        imageView.alpha = 0.0;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
        imageView.image = image;
        imageView.alpha = 1.0;
        [fadeToImageView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I have used Steffen Blass's answer, because it makes more sense to me/ I read it first. Yours looks more advanced, but I don't think i really need it. What would be the advantage of using your method?

Comment: sure.  thanks for the comment.  animations are the way to go to gradually alter view properties.  you might find you need to do dozens at once, with some starting after others end, etc.  view animation - the block approach at the bottom in particular - will let you get the work done without losing your mind keeping track of timers and keeping the correct state in an update method.  just for fun, paste in that second method i suggest and run it.  i promise you you'll end up using block animations and throwing away most of your timers.

Comment: Thanks again. I copied/pasted it into my code, but wasn't sure how to integrate it properly. I've added a dropbox link to my code in the OP, if you care to look at my project. Note that it's my first project that you might actually want to use, so don't expect anything fancy :P.